# How to make the jQuery code working into (function ($){})(); with use strict mode

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works

```
$(".skills").addClass("active")
$(".skills .skill .skill-bar span").each(function() {
   $(this).animate({
      "width": $(this).parent().attr("data-bar") + "%"
   }, 1000);
   $(this).append('<b>' + $(this).parent().attr("data-bar") + '%</b>');
});
setTimeout(function() {
   $(".skills .skill .skill-bar span b").animate({"opacity":"1"},1000);
}, 2000);
```

But when I place the code into (function ($){})(); the code stop working, I tried using both jquery-2.1.3 and jQuery-3.5.1

Comment: Did you mean `$(function() { ..your code.. })` to run on doc ready.  Otherwise it would be `(function($){ code })(jQuery);` to run immediately

Comment: "stop working" isn't a helpful description of the problem. I'd expect it to throw `$ is not a function` but its hard to be sure since you've not show the non-working code as a [mcve]. Just as a somewhat vague description.

Comment: Yes, I tried to mean that $(function() { ..your code.. }) is not functioning properly that should animate a skill bar after loading the doc. But if I place the code, without putting it within the $(function() { .... }) it works and animates the skill bars.